# What is a good method for designing an HTM network in terms of depth and breadth?

Tags: neural-networks

Regarding [Hawkins' HTM algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_temporal_memory). Has anyone found a fruitful method to define the number of nodes in a layer and number of layers in a network?

Comment: I had to look HTM up: Hierarchical Temporal Memory ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_temporal_memory )

Answer (score 4):

The paper [Pattern Recognition by Hierarchical Temporal Memory](http://bias.csr.unibo.it/maltoni/HTM_TR_v1.0.pdf), from Dr. Davide Maltoni in 2011 seems to describe the process in quite some detail. Essentially it seems like the number of nodes and layers depends only on the number of input features, the number of output nodes, and the level over overlap (see section 6.2.3: Overlapping) allowed.